# floating divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

i am trying to create the following positions inside a list tag on my website
[image]

this is my code:

```
<li>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/test/">
        <div class="bt-thumb" style="float:left;background: url(http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/bg1.jpg) no-repeat center center / cover, #333"></div>
    </a>
    <h6 class="">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/test/">Test Post</a>
    </h6>
    <div class="">
        <span>Sep 29, 2016</span>
        <span>By Admin</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

but i just get each element stack on top of each other
any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Look into bootstrap. You'll use a row, two columns, and the rest is history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xc4ky1gj/2/

Couple of things to point out:

First depending on the size of your image and the amount of text you have, there is a very good chance, your floated images will be larger than the content inside. You'll need to add a clearing property to your container to avoid multiple list items stair-stepping.

This can be done by adding the following to your CSS:

```
li {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Remove the clear and overflow attributes from the fiddle to see how the results change without.

I slightly modified your HTML to simplify the mark-up a tad. HTML:

```
<li>
<a href="http://www.example.com/test/" class="bt-thumb" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/100/100);">
Test Photo
</a>
<h6 class="">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/test/">Test Post</a>
</h6>
<div class="">
    <span>Sep 29, 2016</span>
    <span>By Admin</span>
</div>
```

And the accompanying CSS:

```
li {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.bt-thumb {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

(I'm also making the assumption this is contained within a list tag and this is a list of items. Otherwise, your containing element should be switched to a `<div>`)

Answer (score 2):

First of all the html markup, the way how you have wrapped elements inside one-another is terrible ... putting that aside ... this is the minimum working version of what you are asking.

```
.bt-thumb {
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkZkJq

Answer (score -2):

Here's the recipe:

1. Make a container div
2. put everything inside
3. make the contents float
4. give them fixed width